# Compiling dictionary for PhpMorphy

Tags: php, dictionary

How to compile my own dictionary to use with PhpMorphy? For example, if I need dictionary with specific parts of speech (only nouns and adjectives)?

Comment: I have just removed the Russian translation of your question. Stack Overflow [is an English-language website](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange).